# Does "on the weekend" mean "this weekend"? or "every weekend"?

Tags: word-usage

> I don't mind working on the weekend.

Does "on the weekend" mean "this weekend" or "every weekend"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends entirely on the context.

> - I am going to relax on the weekend. (a particular weekend, probably the current weekend.)
> - I do my laundry on the weekend (Suggests a regular activity every weekend.)

The current or immediate weekend is more often "this " weekend than it is 'the" weekend, but "the" can be used in that meaning.

Answer (score -1):

"on the weekend" means "this weekend" or "last weekend" or some specific weekend depending on your context.
If you want to say "on every weekend", you should use "on weekends".

See [Many learners have asked about the difference between these three phrases: over the weekend, on the weekend, and at the weekend. | Ask The Editor | Learner's Dictionary](http://learnersdictionary.com/qa/Over-the-weekend-on-the-weekend-at-the-weekend):

> *Over the weekend* means the same thing as *during the weekend*. It is used to talk about something that **happened (or will happen)**
>   between Friday evening and Sunday evening.
>
> ...
>
> The meaning of ***on the weekend*** is similar to the meaning of *over the
>   weekend*, although it is not used quite as often. The two expressions
>   are usually **interchangeable** and choosing one or the other is
>   mostly a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I don't agree that "on the weekend" can only mean a specific weekend. For example: "Hey, are you coming to the game on Sunday?" "No, sorry, I usually have work on the weekend."